# Help - Compiz fails, no unity, Blank desktop after 13.04 upgrade

Tags: unity, 13.04, upgrade, compiz

I was having Ubuntu 12.10 and then decided to upgrade to 13.10 using Software Updater.

After upgrading, desktop is blank .i.e the unity taskbar, unity bar, etc.. is not showing up....

I installed Nvidia-current driver. But this didn't help.

Then I switched to terminal  `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and issued
`DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace`. But this is also not helping.

Its giving me below result
`compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct`.

I have desktop of below configurations:

- Asus Motherboard.
- Intel Core i5 processor - Generation I
- 4GB RAM
- Nvidia 9600GT Graphic Card

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Sir,

I have desktop of below configurations: Asus Motherboard. Intel Core i5 processor - Generation I 4GB RAM Nvidia 9600GT Graphic Card